# Would it be problematic to delete SymPy manually and reinstall it?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, sympy, anaconda3

**Long story short: I fucked up. I had a problem with sympy. Would I get a problem if I deleted the sympy folder manually and installed it via anaconda prompt again?**

I had an error all the time saying class_registry was deprecated. So I deleted that one. Then I got another package that was deprecated and removed that one. Now it says it can't import something called 'C' anymore because of an unknown location when I import sympy

I wanted to just reinstall sympy, but when I typed the command in Anaconda Prompt(because I have spyder installed via anaconda):

> conda install sympy --force-reinstall

It said the package for sympy was corrupted, so it couldn't reïnstall. I wanted to just open the Windows Verkenner (Windows Explorer in english I think?) and delete the entire sympy folder and install it again via the Prompt. So would it be a bad idea to do?

Comment: You should create a new environment or reinstall Anaconda instead. Just removing the folder could give other headaches.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba What do you mean by 'new environment'? I want to look up how to do that, but I need to have a more specific term for that

Comment: Sorry for the brevity, I meant [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).